# useState() is not updating state from event handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to recreate an old flash game in React. The object of the game is to press a button  down for a certain length of time.

This is the old game:
http://www.zefrank.com/everysecond/index.html

Here is my new React implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/inspectordanno/every_second

I'm running into a problem. When the mouse is released, I calculate the amount of time between when the button was pressed and when it was released, using the Moment.js time library. If the `timeDifference` between the `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` event is within the `targetTime`, I want the game `level` to increase and the `targetTime` to increase as well.

I'm implementing this logic in the `handleMouseUp` event handler. I'm getting the expected times printed to the screen, but the logic isn't working. In addition, when I `console.log()` the times, they are different than the ones being printed to the screen. I'm fairly certain `timeHeld` and `timeDifference` aren't being updated correctly.

Initially I thought there was a problem with the way I was doing the event handler and I need to use `useRef()` or `useCallback()`, but after browsing a few other questions I don't understand these well enough to know if I have to use them in this situation. Since I don't need access to the previous state, I don't think I need to use them, right?

The game logic is in this wrapper component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Button from './Button';
import Level from './Level';
import TargetTime from './TargetTime';
import TimeIndicator from './TimeIndicator';
import Tries from './Tries';

const TimerApp = () => {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(1);
  const [targetTime, setTargetTime] = useState(.2);
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const [whenPressed, setPressed] = useState(moment());
  const [whenReleased, setReleased] = useState(moment());
  const [tries, setTries] = useState(3);
  const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);

  const timeHeld = whenReleased.diff(whenPressed) / 1000;
  let timeDifference = Math.abs(targetTime - timeHeld);
  timeDifference = Math.round(1000 * timeDifference) / 1000; //rounded

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    !gameStarted && setGameStarted(true); //initialize game on the first click
    setIsPressed(true);
    setPressed(moment());
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsPressed(false);
    setReleased(moment());

    console.log(timeHeld);
    console.log(timeDifference);

    if (timeDifference <= .1) {
      setLevel(level + 1);
      setTargetTime(targetTime + .2);
    } else if (timeDifference > .1 && tries >= 1) {
      setTries(tries - 1);
    }

    if (tries === 1) {
      setGameOver(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Level level={level}/>
      <TargetTime targetTime={targetTime} />
      <Button handleMouseDown={handleMouseDown} handleMouseUp={handleMouseUp} isGameOver={gameOver} />
      <TimeIndicator timeHeld={timeHeld} timeDifference={timeDifference} isPressed={isPressed} gameStarted={gameStarted} />
      <Tries tries={tries} />
      {gameOver && <h1>Game Over!</h1>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TimerApp;
```

If you want to check the whole app please refer to the sandbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you update some state inside a function, and then try to use that state in the same function, it will not use the updated values. Functions snapshots the values of state when function is called and uses that throughout the function. This was not a case in class component's `this.setState`, but this is the case in hooks. `this.setState` also doesn't updates the values eagerly, but it can update while in the same function depending on a few things(which I am not qualified enough to explain).
To use updated values you need a ref. Hence use a `useRef` hook. [[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)]
I have fixed you code you can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/everysecond-4uqvv?fontsize=14
It can be written in a better way but that you will have to do yourself.

Adding code in answer too for completion(with some comments to explain stuff, and suggest improvements):

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Button from "./Button";
import Level from "./Level";
import TargetTime from "./TargetTime";
import TimeIndicator from "./TimeIndicator";
import Tries from "./Tries";

const TimerApp = () => {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(1);
  const [targetTime, setTargetTime] = useState(0.2);
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const whenPressed = useRef(moment());
  const whenReleased = useRef(moment());
  const [tries, setTries] = useState(3);
  const [gameStarted, setGameStarted] = useState(false);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);
  const timeHeld = useRef(null);  // make it a ref instead of just a variable
  const timeDifference = useRef(null);  // make it a ref instead of just a variable

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    !gameStarted && setGameStarted(true); //initialize game on the first click
    setIsPressed(true);
    whenPressed.current = moment();
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsPressed(false);
    whenReleased.current = moment();

    timeHeld.current = whenReleased.current.diff(whenPressed.current) / 1000;
    timeDifference.current = Math.abs(targetTime - timeHeld.current);
    timeDifference.current = Math.round(1000 * timeDifference.current) / 1000; //rounded

    console.log(timeHeld.current);
    console.log(timeDifference.current);

    if (timeDifference.current <= 0.1) {
      setLevel(level + 1);
      setTargetTime(targetTime + 0.2);
    } else if (timeDifference.current > 0.1 && tries >= 1) {
      setTries(tries - 1);
      // consider using ref for tries as well to get rid of this weird tries === 1 and use tries.current === 0
      if (tries === 1) {
        setGameOver(true);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Level level={level} />
      <TargetTime targetTime={targetTime} />
      <Button
        handleMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        handleMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        isGameOver={gameOver}
      />
      <TimeIndicator
        timeHeld={timeHeld.current}
        timeDifference={timeDifference.current}
        isPressed={isPressed}
        gameStarted={gameStarted}
      />
      <Tries tries={tries} />
      {gameOver && <h1>Game Over!</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TimerApp;
```

PS: Don't use unnecessary third party libraries, especially big ones like MomentJs. They increase your bundle size significantly. Use can easily get current timestamp using vanilla js. `Date.now()` will give you current unix timestamp, you can subtract two timestamps to get the duration in ms.

Also you have some unnecessary state like `gameOver`, you can just check `if tries > 0` to decide gameOver.
Similarly instead of `targetTime` you can just use `level * .2`, no need to additional state.
Also `whenReleased` doesn't needs to be a ref or state, it can be just a local variable in mouseup handler.

Comment: `useRef` in this case is not the right thing... `whenPressed` and `timeHeld` should be 'managed by' `useState` ... `timeDifference` is a derived value, can be calculated on render

Comment: to calculate `timeHeld`, `whenPressed` is required. Unless you move calculations to a new function, `whenPressed` needs to be a ref.

Comment: no, it's once calculated, it's a calculation param ... `whenPressed` can be a local variable in event handler.... `timeHeld` is a result of this calculation, this should be stored

Comment: bro `whenPressed` happens on `onMouseDown` and `timeHeld` will be calculated on `onMouseUp`. How will you access the local variable of `handleMouseDown` in `handleMouseUp`.

Comment: ups, sorry.... I've copy/pasted wrong variable name - should be `whenReleased`... you're right, you must store `whenPressed` on `onMouseDown` ... but on `onMouseUp` current time can be assigned to a local `whenReleased` and used in time difference calculations (result stored in `timeHeld`) - you can even use current time directly in calculations (without using `whenReleased`) ... `timeDifference` can be stored (`useState`) but (as derived, formatted only) can be calculated locally (like in classic 'render')

Answer (score 5):

State updaters can take a value indicating the new state, or a function that maps the current state to a new state. The latter is the right tool for the job when you have state that depends on mutations of itself.

This should work if you update places in the code where you use the pattern

```
[value, setValue ] = useState(initial);
...
setValue(value + change);
```

to

```
[value, setValue ] = useState(initial);
...
setValue((curValue) => curValue + change);
```

For example,

```
if (timeDifference <= .1) {
  setLevel((curLevel) => curLevel + 1);
  setTargetTime((curTarget) => curTarget + .2);
} else if (timeDifference > .1 && tries >= 1) {
  setTries((curTries) => {
    const newTries = curTries - 1;
    if (newTries === 1) {
      setGameOver(true);
    }
    return newTries;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two subtle things going on here:

1. When you call a `setState` method (e.g. `setRelease(moment())`) the value of the associated variable (e.g. `whenReleased`) does not update immediately. Instead it queues a re-render, and only once that render happens will the value be updated.
2. The event handlers (e.g. `handleMouseUp`) are closures. Meaning they capture the values from the parent scope. And again therefor are only updated *on a re-render*. So, when `handleMouseUp` runs, `timeDifference` (and `timeHeld`) will be the value that was calculated during the last render.

The changes you therefore need to make are:

1. Move the calculation of `timeDifference` inside your `handleMouseUp` event handler.
2. Instead of using `whenReleased` in your `timeDifference` calculation, you need to use a local variable set to `moment()` (You can *also* set `whenReleased` via `setReleased`, but that value won't be available to you inside your event handler).

```
  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    const released = moment();

    setIsPressed(false);
    setReleased(released);

    const timeHeld = released.diff(whenPressed) / 1000;
    const timeDifference = Math.round(1000 * Math.abs(targetTime - timeHeld)) / 1000;

    console.log(timeHeld);
    console.log(timeDifference);

    if (timeDifference <= .1) {
      setLevel(level + 1);
      setTargetTime(targetTime + .2);
    } else if (timeDifference > .1 && tries >= 1) {
      setTries(tries - 1);
    }

    if (tries === 1) {
      setGameOver(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: If `timeHeld` and `timeDifference` are local to this function, how is it supposed to be used to render it's values in the return method.

Answer (score 0):

> When the mouse is released, I calculate the amount of time between when the button was pressed and when it was released...

**This is not true** ... but can be ... just move the time difference calulations into `handleMouseUp()`

... also - you don't need `whenReleased`

Comment: i've moved them into handleMouseUp() and it is still not working :(